# Проверить включен ли GPS на Android

Tags: java, android, gps

Воспользовался [этим решением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22980843/1776312)

```
    public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

    }else{
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }
}
```

Но этот метод всегда возвращает true, не зависимо включен или выключен GPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону **LocationManager**

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);;
    boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
//enabled true если включен GPS
```

Ну и не забудьте о пермишене в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Прослушка GPS - Android](http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread1168910.html) - вот глянь